# How can I fix this so that Azure Pipelines can build the MAUI iOS app when it needs different profiles for different parts?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, azure-pipelines, maui

I'm using Azure Pipelines to make an iOS app using MAUI. This app needs an extension for push notifications, which requires separate profiles for both the app and the extension.

But, when I try to build using Azure Pipelines, it fails. It says the profiles for the app and the extension don't match.

How can I fix this so that Azure Pipelines can build the app when it needs different profiles for different parts?

This is what the yaml file looks like:

> ```
> trigger:
>   branches:
>     include:
>       - develop
>
> variables:
>     BuildConfiguration: Release
>     DotNetVersion: 8.x
>     iOSVersion: net8.0-ios
>
> pool:
>   vmImage: macos-latest
>   demands: xcode
>
> steps:
> - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
>   displayName: 'Install Apple P12 Cert'
>   inputs:
>     certSecureFile: 'apple_prod_signing_cert.p12'
>     certPwd: '$(AppleCertificatePassword)'
>     keychain: 'temp'
>
> - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
>   displayName: 'Install Apple Provisioning Profile'
>   inputs:
>     provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
>     provProfileSecureFile: 'apple_ad_hoc_com.mobileprovision'
>
> - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
>   displayName: 'Install Provisioning Profile for App Extension'
>   inputs:
>     provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
>     provProfileSecureFile: 'Development_Notification_Extension.mobileprovision'
>
> - task: UseDotNet@2
>   inputs:
>     packageType: 'sdk'
>     version: '$(DotNetVersion)'
>
> - task: CmdLine@2
>   displayName: 'Install Maui Workload'
>   inputs:
>     script: 'dotnet workload install maui'
>
> - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
>   displayName: 'dotnet publish $(BuildConfiguration)'
>   inputs:
>     command: 'publish'
>     publishWebProjects: false
>     projects: '**/*.csproj'
>     arguments: '-f:$(iOSVersion) -c:$(BuildConfiguration) -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64'
>     zipAfterPublish: false
>     modifyOutputPath: false
>   env:
>     DISABLE_BITCODE: 'yes'
>
> - task: CopyFiles@2
>   displayName: 'Copy file from Build to Staging'
>   inputs:
>     SourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
>     Contents: '**/*.ipa'
>     TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
>     flattenFolders: true
>
> - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
>   displayName: 'Publish the Staging Files.'
>   inputs:
>     PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
>     ArtifactName: 'drop_maui_ios'
>     publishLocation: 'Container'
> ```

I'm facing challenges while using Azure Pipelines to build my iOS app and its associated notification extension. The build process is hitting roadblocks due to issues with provisioning profiles and code signing keys.

For my iOS app, I'm encountering an error indicating that the specified iOS provisioning profile ('Ad Hoc com.cin.app') cannot be found. Simultaneously, the iOS code signing key ('Apple Distribution: Cin') is reported as missing in the keychain for the app's notification extension.

Furthermore, the recent Azure Pipelines update includes .NET 5.x SDK/Runtime alongside older .NET Core versions. This update might be causing compatibility issues with projects that rely on specific SDK versions. The error messages recommend using particular versions of NuGet or SDK, or altering the restoration process to mitigate these issues.